# copy entire column of an excel to another depends upon change in a cell value

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

My requirement is whenever there is an update to my main workbook's (main.xlsm)sheet1 "A1" cell, I need to copy that entire row of data into a different excel(say working.xlsm). The main sheet has columns from A to M and data capture should occur depends upon A1 cell data change. All data get preserved in the second excel and all new data will be added to next row.

I have added below code to my second workbook(working.xlsm), where I need to save all the data, but it's not working. I am not sure how to use a range with `with` function

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

With Sheet1
    With .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)
        If .Value <> Workbooks("main.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Val‌ue  Then
            .Offset(1).Value = Sheet1.Range("A:M").Value
        End If
    End With
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: having nested with statements is unnecessary. just use `With Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Row.Count, "B").End(xlUp)`. You also don't define Sheet1

Comment: Also you must have the "main.xlsm" workbook open to reference it like that

Comment: If you are watching changes occuring in the main workbook, you should put this code inside it.

Comment: I'm a little confused by what exactly you're trying to do, but if you're trying to run code when A1 of one of main.xlsm's sheets changes, you should put this code in that sheet: `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) : If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then` and then whatever you're trying to do.

Comment: @J.Fox:         Yes, when A1 changes, I need that new value in A1 to be copied to a different workbook along with B:M cell values

Comment: @sourceCode     :main.xlsm will be always open.

Answer (score 1):

This code will, if put in the sheet on main.xlsm, copy A1:M1 of main.xlsm to the first blank row of working.xlsm's Sheet1 whenever A1 of the sheet is changed. This assumes that working.xlsm is currently open as well, for reference.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Workbooks("working").Sheets("Sheet1")
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then 
    Range("A1:M1").Copy 
    ws.Range("A" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End If
End Sub
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Thanks. how can I paste only the values from A1:M1 to working sheet . the main sheet will contain formulas but I need only the values to be copied

Comment: Its still has some issues while I use formula in A1   https://www.dropbox.com/sh/haxoxgtldqmdcxe/AAB5_SG95Woho6wnB8X4ynUIa?dl=0

Comment: Added a sample main and working sheet here. If I refer C5 value to A1 and I update A1 through C5, it i not getting copied to working sheet

Comment: The code only checks to see if cell A1 is changed: if you want it to check if A1 or C5 is changed, use `If Not Intersect(Target, Union(Range("A1"), Range("C5"))) Is Nothing Then` instead of the normal `If`.

Comment: I would like to check only A1. but the changes for A1 will happen through its formula, not a manual entry to A1. to test that I made A1=C5 and updated the value in C5, which inturn change A1. but that is not working

Comment: I did some edit to the code and its working. Thanks for giving the lead